# Create-React-App with Jest not working "Cannot find module nodeModuleX from componentY"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to start testing the components on my project that was created with the Create React App with Jest. I created a simple test file for one component and I'm getting this "error" coming from a component that isn't even related to the component I'm trying to test. I'm using the Create React App, so I can't change jest's config.

**That's the test file**

```
/** Home.test.js */

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from '../../components/Home';

test('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Home />, div);
 });
```

**That's the error**

```
FAIL  src\__tests__\components\Home.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'signature_pad' from 'Signature.jsx'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:179:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/common/inputs/Signature.jsx:3:22)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.031s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

**If I comment the import line of the code on the component Signature.jsx, I get another error from another component:**

```
src\__tests__\components\Home.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _WorkerDriverLicenceSchema2.default is not iterable

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/profiles/worker/forms/WorkerDriverLicences.jsx:35:33)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/profiles/worker/subComponents/WorkerViewDetails.jsx:18:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/profiles/worker/subComponents/WorkerDetailsModal.jsx:7:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/common/uiElements/UserDetailsLink.jsx:7:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/common/uiElements/index.js:13:247)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/common/layout/ChangeLog.jsx:5:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/common/layout/index.js:1:182)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Home.jsx:4:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/components/Home.test.js:5:13)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.18s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```